# JQuery keyup event not starting up

Tags: python, jquery, flask, bootstrap-4, keyup

I have been trying to use the following code.

I want to route to /search whenever a letter is entered but the code will not reroute. I dont see what i am doing wrong.

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %} The Latin Library Search {% endblock %}


<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
  $(function() {
    var submit_form = function(e) {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/search', {
        q: $('input[name="q"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $('#result').text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    };

    $('a#submit').bind('click', submit_form);

    $('input[type=search]').bind('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode) {
        submit_form(e);
      }
    });

  });
 </script>



 {% block content %}
 <div class="container">
<h1>Search engine for The Latin Library</h1>
<form >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="code">search with author name, book title or sentence</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="search" name="q">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></a>
    </div>
</form>

<hr/>
 <span id=result>?</span>
</div>

  {% endblock %}
```

When i run my application and enter the letter 'q' i get the following log:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 173-866-966
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018 17:28:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018 17:29:01] "GET /?q=q HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It should be:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018 17:29:01] "GET /search?q=q HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**UPDATE:**
I just realized that the 'keyup' event itself is not being recognized for some reason.

I am still not able to solve the issue i just realized something else might be a cause for it.

Comment: try the preventDefault() method

Comment: Tried preventDefault() got the same result

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake.

```
http:
```

should not be used while importing any files.
so instead it should be.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
```